# How to define com.google.protobuf.Message as message type in .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

How to define generic message in proto file.

Eg :

```
message GenericResponse
{
    bool status = 1;
    Foo foo= 2;
    Bar bar = 3;
    Baz baz = 4;
}
```

Instead of above mentioned protocol I need following protocol.

```
message GenericResponse
{
    bool status = 1;
    google.protobuf.Message response = 2;
}
```

I need to set `Foo` or `Bar` or `Baz` values in `response`.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#using-oneof) is your best bet:

```
message GenericResponse
{
    bool status = 1;
    oneof response {
        Foo foo= 2;
        Bar bar = 3;
        Baz baz = 4;
    }
}
```

You could also use [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any), but IMO that would be a mistake and would make things harder for you.

Comment: But I will get the result like this : "status: true bar { id: 6 }". 
What I Expect is "status: true response { id: 6 }" .

Comment: @prasath yes, because without that : you won't know which it represents. The serializer wants to know.

Comment: Like Object in java I need to define Message in proto file. If not possible I will go with "oneof".

Comment: @Prasath the closest thing to Object is Any. It does mean hat you'll have to do extra work to fetch the value, though. But: IMO this is a mistake. You don't usually actually mean "any" - usually you mean "an unknown one of these expected types", I suspect. Which would be: "oneof"

Comment: I ll go with "oneof"

Comment: Hi Marc...Can you please educate me how to exercise a simple helloworld program using protobuf?Its confusing.Can you plz point to step by step tutorial?

Comment: @sskumar86 refer to the documentation of either protobuf or your specific library. If you have a specific question, you'd need to explain what is still unclear after reading the documentation